# Sampled vs population relative frequency distribution

Tags: chi-squared-test, relative-distribution

Assume I have a real count of people by city, and I have 4 cities, A,B,C,D (for simplicity), and the people distribute 30%, 30%, 25%, 15% respectively.
I also have a sample of this population, which is distributed let's say, 33%, 26%, 28%, 13%.
Now I would like to measure whether these distributions are significantly different.

I think I can use chi-square goodness of fit test for that, but I'm not sure if I violate any assumptions doing that in this case. Am I missing anything else with this approach?
Will I be able to use it with many more cities?

Thank you

Comment: *"a sample of this population"* How did you sample? The [Pearson's chi-square goodness of fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) works for samples that follow a categorical distribution.

Comment: You need numbers rather than just proportions.  How many were sampled?

Comment: @Henry I have 18k areas (in practice are smaller than cities). On average per area I have a count of around 180, and actual population is around 3k. I want to know if the distributions between the areas are different or not.